# GET WebView's WebNavigatedEventArgs Result Error Code when successful in .NET MAUI

Tags: webview, maui

It seems that when Navigated event occurs, the Result from the navigation of the WebView in .NET MAUI is successful, no matter that the response status is 401 for example. (Unauthorized).

I was counting that it will be Failure, for anything but 2xx.
Is there a way to detect problem when loading the WebView?

(Perhaps without writing too much platform specific code)

Edit(adding some related code):

```
void Navigated(WebNavigatedEventArgs args)
{            
    if (args.Result == WebNavigationResult.Failure)
    {
        IsConnectionOK = false;
    }
}
```

The Result here is success, not failure.
The HTTP response status of the request is 401. (Unauthorized)

Comment: Could you provide some code related ?

Comment: Sure. If this is not enough, just tell me.

Comment: If you use `HttpClient`, you can add a `if` judge `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` whether true or false.

Comment: Can I do this with WebView?

Comment: Have you edited some code to make a request to web API by `HttpClient` ?

Comment: I do not want to make requests to web API. I want to load a web page in a WebView. (Edit: If you suggest to make a request to get a html, and set it as HTML content of the WebView, it wont work for any, but the most simple cases)

Comment: Usually we check Log or diagnostics,  and could you provide some details about Log or diagnostic?

Comment: Are we talking about the debug output? There is nothing there to indicate any difference in the response code. You see the same thing, no matter if is 2xx, 4xx, or anything else. The more I am digging into this, the more it seems to me as if no one cares about the response code. As long as there is response...

Comment: Since you said that the response status is 401(Unauthorized), it means that the page needs User authentication : username and password should be set to the `request`'s  authentication header .You want to load the web page in a WebView. So you have to make a request to login or whatever. WebView can not detect response code error. WebView is just a view for displaying web and HTML content in your app.

Comment: First of all, it is really bad practice to send username and password for authorization. Second, In my practice I have used WebView to display pages (in more than one platform), and detecting problem when loading the page wasn't an issue. The WebView is indeed used for displaying a web. The problem here is that you do not know if you are actually displaying the web or not. Not really useful.

Comment: Unfortunately detecting response status code error can not implement in .forms or maui. However, you do it in ios or android firstly, and then use it in maui or .forms by dependency service .